# Tkinter page not loading

Tags: python, tkinter, init

One of my pages in my Tkinter program isn't loading. I am not sure why

There is a `get()` method within my `InsertOperation` class which is meant to retrieve the value of a selected radiobuttion from the previous class and execute the appropriate portion of my code. However, this `get()` method doesn't seem to be doing that. Is there an alternative to this?

```py
class MyOMSApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for op in (MainPage, InsertMenu, InsertOperation):
            my_ops = op(container, self)
            self.frames[op] = my_ops
            my_ops.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
            my_ops.grid(row=550, column=550, sticky='nsew')
            self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        my_ops = self.frames[cont]
        my_ops.tkraise()


class MainPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, run):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        main_label = Label(self, text="WELCOME TO THE OFFICE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM")
        main_label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        second_label = Label(self, text="Welcome\n\nChoose Your Operation", fg='black', width=40, font=20)
        second_label.pack(pady=40, padx=50)
        Button(self, text="INSERT", width=10, bg='cyan', command=lambda: run.show_frame(InsertMenu), font=20).pack(pady=160, padx=20)

class InsertMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, run):
        global table_op
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        Label(self, text="CREATE RECORD\n\nChoose Table to Begin", fg='black', width=20, font=("bold", 20)).pack(padx=130, pady=30)
        table_op = IntVar()
        Radiobutton(self, text="Personnel Records", variable=table_op, value=1).place(x=60, y=160)
        Radiobutton(self, text="Office Inventory", variable=table_op, value=2).place(x=320, y=160)
        Radiobutton(self, text="Company", variable=table_op, value=3).place(x=60, y=190)
        Radiobutton(self, text="Office Accounting Records", variable=table_op, value=4).place(x=320, y=190)
        Radiobutton(self, text="Contract Records", variable=table_op, value=5).place(x=60, y=220)
        Button(self, text="Select", width=20, command=lambda: run.show_frame(InsertOperation), bg="green", fg="white").place(x=60, y=300)

class InsertOperation(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, run):

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Label(self, text="CREATE RECORD\n\nChoose Table to Begin", fg='black', width=20, font=("bold", 20)).pack(padx=130, pady=30)
        table_select = table_op.get()
        if table_select == 1:
            Label(self, text="INSERT STAFF RECORDS", font=("bold", 20)).place(x=35, y=10)
            Label(self, text="First Name", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=50)
            Label(self, text="Last Name", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=100)
            Label(self, text="Position", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=150)
            Label(self, text="Address", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=200)
            Label(self, text="Salary", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=250)
            f_name = Entry(self, width=40)
            f_name.place(x=120, y=55)
            l_name = Entry(self, width=40)
            l_name.place(x=120, y=105)
            post = Entry(self, width=40)
            post.place(x=120, y=155)
            addy = Entry(self, width=40)
            addy.place(x=120, y=205)
            wages = Entry(self, width=40)
            wages.place(x=120, y=255)


app = MyOMSApp()
app.mainloop()
```

no error message

Comment: do you get error message? Which `get()` doesn't work ? All pages are created at start (before you even see window) so if you use `get()` in `__init__` then it is executed before you can use any widget. You may have to use `get()` in function which will be executed when you change pages.

Comment: if you use `print()` in all `__init__` then you see that they are executed before you see window - when widgets are empty and not-selected yet.

Comment: Where is this `get()` method within the class defined? Please [edit] your question and add it.

Comment: @martineau on the 4th line of the InserOperation class

Comment: This line of code isn't working: ###table_select = table_op.get().###. line 4 of within the InserOperation class

Comment: 4th line is executed when you start program, not after you select element and change page. You have to use it in function which you will run when you change page.

Comment: @furas like an intermediate function then?

Comment: @furas I guess you are right. If I use print, it returns 0 even immediately I start the program

Comment: in every `Page` create function ie. 'update_page' and add `my_ops.update_page()` in `show_frame`. Now `update_page` will be executed when you change page. And now you can move  `get()` to `update_page` in `InsertOperation`

Comment: rmclaw: That's line **isn't** the definition of a method — it's just assigning the return value of calling the `get()` method of the global `IntVar()` variable named `table_op` to a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All classes are created at start so all code in `__init__` is executed at start even before you see window and `get()` take value before you can select element.

You have to use `get()` in function which will be executed when you change pages/frames.

You can add in all pages function ie. `update_page` (don't use name `update()` because tkinter already uses this name) and execute it in `show frame` as `my_ops.update_page()`

Now you can move `get()` to `update_page()`

```
from tkinter import *

class MyOMSApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for op in (MainPage, InsertMenu, InsertOperation):
            my_ops = op(container, self)
            self.frames[op] = my_ops
            my_ops.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
            my_ops.grid(row=550, column=550, sticky='nsew')
            self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        my_ops = self.frames[cont]
        my_ops.update_page()  # <--
        my_ops.tkraise()


class MainPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, run):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        main_label = Label(self, text="WELCOME TO THE OFFICE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM")
        main_label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        second_label = Label(self, text="Welcome\n\nChoose Your Operation", fg='black', width=40, font=20)
        second_label.pack(pady=40, padx=50)
        Button(self, text="INSERT", width=10, bg='cyan', command=lambda: run.show_frame(InsertMenu), font=20).pack(pady=160, padx=20)

    def update_page(self):
        pass

class InsertMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, run):
        global table_op
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        Label(self, text="CREATE RECORD\n\nChoose Table to Begin", fg='black', width=20, font=("bold", 20)).pack(padx=130, pady=30)
        table_op = IntVar()
        Radiobutton(self, text="Personnel Records", variable=table_op, value=1).place(x=60, y=160)
        Radiobutton(self, text="Office Inventory", variable=table_op, value=2).place(x=320, y=160)
        Radiobutton(self, text="Company", variable=table_op, value=3).place(x=60, y=190)
        Radiobutton(self, text="Office Accounting Records", variable=table_op, value=4).place(x=320, y=190)
        Radiobutton(self, text="Contract Records", variable=table_op, value=5).place(x=60, y=220)
        Button(self, text="Select", width=20, command=lambda: run.show_frame(InsertOperation), bg="green", fg="white").place(x=60, y=300)

    def update_page(self):   # <--
        pass 

class InsertOperation(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, run):

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Label(self, text="CREATE RECORD\n\nChoose Table to Begin", fg='black', width=20, font=("bold", 20)).pack(padx=130, pady=30)

    def update_page(self):   # <--
        table_select = table_op.get()
        print(table_select)
        if table_select == 1:
            Label(self, text="INSERT STAFF RECORDS", font=("bold", 20)).place(x=35, y=10)
            Label(self, text="First Name", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=50)
            Label(self, text="Last Name", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=100)
            Label(self, text="Position", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=150)
            Label(self, text="Address", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=200)
            Label(self, text="Salary", font=("bold", 12)).place(x=30, y=250)
            f_name = Entry(self, width=40)
            f_name.place(x=120, y=55)
            l_name = Entry(self, width=40)
            l_name.place(x=120, y=105)
            post = Entry(self, width=40)
            post.place(x=120, y=155)
            addy = Entry(self, width=40)
            addy.place(x=120, y=205)
            wages = Entry(self, width=40)
            wages.place(x=120, y=255)

app = MyOMSApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you @furas. Had to move some other line of code around. But it works perfectly.